# Universal link not working in iOS < 9.3

Tags: ios9, ios-universal-links

I have followed every required step to setup universal link in iOS 9.0 & above. It works properly on iOS 9.3 but still open urls in safari in lower versions.

This is how my apple-app-site-association file looks in safari

```
    {
     "applinks":
     {
      "apps":
       [],
      "details":
       [
        {
         "appID":
         "XXXXXXXXXX.com.XXXXX.XXXXX",
         "paths":
          [
           "*"
          ]
        }
       ]
      }
    }
```

How can I make it work in iOS 9.0 to 9.2 just like 9.3

----------------- Update -----------------

Now it is working.... The issue was if I click ***http(s)/mydomain.com*** in iOS9.3 it opens the app but same doen't work for iOS version >9.0 & <9.3. for that I had to use ***http(s)/mydomain.com/some_path***. It is strange isn't it?

Comment: This looks correct, so it *should* be working...are you testing it on physical devices with each iOS version? Try the validator [here](http://branch.io/resources/universal-links/)

Comment: @Alex : validator says 'Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.' but I don't think that is an issue. as it works on iOS9.3 device.